# Appium along with Sikuli for Mobile App testing

Tags: java, appium, sikuli, sikuli-script, mobile-app-testing

I was trying to use Sikuli for Image Identification along with Appium.

So, when I tried finding an image after launching app on device using Appium, but Sikuli returned an error saying, "cannot find img/x.png on the screen".

Note: I want the test to be run on real device and not emulator.

Comment: I wonder if we can do that with real device. As far as I know, Sikuli takes the control of screen of desktop and mouse/keyboard when you instantiate its object. For that, application needs to be open on screen and not on other devices. (sikuli can be run on remote desktops but devices I am doubtful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sikuli is an automation tool designed for desktops. Not mobile. Sikuli automates anything you see on the desktop screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components.
So All the images which you are trying to capture should be on the desktop screen. 
If you are using an real device I recommend you to use screen casting to mirror the device in to the desktop and run Sikuli commands.

Screen mirroring useful links:

http://www.droidscreencast.com/

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/mirroring_an_android_device_screen_onto_your_desktop?lang=en

Comment: I can not reach the page -->  http://www.droidscreencast.com/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to use Sikuli for mobile too. With Appium.
[Here is example](http://dzaiats.github.io/appium-sikuli-driver/) of how to do it. 
in this project is described the process how to setup and how to use this framework. Examples are attached.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.